# MySQL: Create one row per month for data having date ranges

Tags: mysql, grouping, date-range

**!Modified!**

I have a table (mySQL 5.0.x) which contains values for date ranges.

```
| id | link_id | type_id | value |  start | end    |
====================================================
|  1 |       1 |       1 |    10 | 201111 | 201202 |
|  2 |       1 |       2 |    20 | 201110 | 201201 |
|  3 |       1 |       1 |   100 | 201202 | 201202 |
|  4 |       2 |       1 |    40 | 201202 | 201203 |
```

where

- **id** is the id for record
- **link_id** is for linking the data to other tables
- **type_id** is for determining the type of the value from other table
- **value** is numerical value
- **start** and **end** define the range (real date or integer for year and month)

The trick is that I need to present total value per type and link for a given period on a monthly basis. So the result should be like this for the range 201201 - 201202:

```
| period | link_id | type_id | value |
======================================
| 201201 |       1 |       1 |    10 |
| 201202 |       1 |       1 |   110 |
| 201201 |       1 |       2 |    20 |
| 201201 |       2 |    NULL |  NULL |
| 201202 |       2 |       1 |    40 |
```

I could use PHP to put the information like this into the database but there are some drawbacks. I have hundreds of link_ids, many type_id, and the average difference between start and end dates is 30 months so I would have tons of rows.

Comment: how start and end are stored, are DATE fields?

Comment: It depends on the solution. They can be some kind of dates or 6 digit integers. I used 6 digit integers because of some mysql _PERIOD_ function but it is not a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I've put in `$startMonth` and `$endMonth` so you can see how they play in. (I have this niggling feeling this can be simplified, but it currenty escapes me):

```
SET @MONTH:=$startMonth-1;

SELECT month, link_id, type_id, SUM(value) AS value
FROM (SELECT @MONTH:=@MONTH+1 as month
      FROM foo f
      LIMIT $endMonth-$startMonth+1) a
LEFT JOIN foo f
 ON a.month >= f.start AND a.month <= f.end
GROUP BY link_id, type_id, a.month;
```

The way it works: suppose you had a table `a`:

```
+-------+
| month |
+-------+
|201201 |
|201202 |
+-------+
```

Then the query you're after is a lot simpler to work out:

```
SELECT month, link_id, type_id, SUM(value) AS value
FROM a
LEFT JOIN foo
 ON a.month >= f.start AND a.month <= f.end
GROUP BY link_id, type_id, a.month;
```

Ie you join table `a` to `foo` by making sure the `month` is between the start and end periods, and then you just sum up value, grouping by month, link id, and type id.

So the problem is how to generate table `a` which contains numbers from `$startMonth` to `$endMonth`. Hence the:

```
SET @MONTH:=201200;
SELECT @MONTH:=@MONTH+1 AS month
FROM foo
LIMIT 2;
```

This gives a table of numbers startign from `201201` and with 2 rows, ie up to `201202`. In this query the `FROM foo` is dummy - not really used.

Comment: Thanks! Almost perfect. Two issues (one is mine). 1) After 201112 the next value is 201113 instead of 201201 but I can handle with a pre-built table. 2) I did not tell that I need to have NULL values for month not having values for the given period. ( **I have modified the question!** )

Comment: `SELECT @MONTH:=@MONTH+1 AS month` should be `SELECT @MONTH := PERIOD_ADD( @MONTH , 1 ) AS month` for precise operation and table `foo` has to have at least as many rows as the difference between start and end date.

Comment: Oh, I knew I was forgetting something with the dates wrapping around. And good point with `foo` needing at least that many rows. I suppose there must be another way to do this. (Why oh why doesn't MySQL have a "SELECT INT i WHERE i BETWEEN xx and yy"?)

Comment: I realized that your solution is what I needed. MySql sometimes behave strange. Anyway thanks for the help it was just great.